# Updating map automatically when address is changed manually

Tags: dictionary, scripting, field, street-address

I have a site where I will be manually changing street addresses.  I want to include a map link but I want it to update itself automatically when I change addresses...

Also, I'd like the link to send the address field to google maps or mapquest and return with that info in a small popup window that features the map.  What's the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Mapeed Address Chooser](http://github.com/mapeed/addresschooser)

The demo link is currently down though....